# Javascript (jquery) in my rails app is crashing IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I've got a ruby on rails app where I'm using a table to display some data, and then allowing the user to edit the data in the table by clicking on the row and popping up a form for the relevant data. When changes are made to the form, the appropriate row in the table is updated.

The event listener for the table row click, which displays the appropriate form, looks like this:

```
$('.addable-rows > tbody').on('click', 'tr', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var fieldset = $($(this).data('id'));
  if ($(this).hasClass('selected')){
    $(this).removeClass('selected');
    fieldset.hide('slow');
  } else {
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    fieldset.siblings().hide('slow');
    fieldset.show('slow');
  }
});
```

The listener that checks for changes in inputs on the form and updates the appropriate row in the table looks like this:

```
$('.addable_row_host').on('change', ':input', function(){
  var fieldset = $(this).closest('fieldset')
  var id = fieldset.attr('id')
  $('#'+id+'_tr').replaceWith(build_row(fieldset, id));
});
```

The build row method referenced above is:

```
function build_row(fields, id){
  row = $("<tr id='"+id+"_tr' data-id='#"+id+"' class='selected'></tr>");
  fields.find('select, input:not([type=hidden])').each(function(){
    val = $(this).val();
    if(val == null){
      val = '';
    }else if(val.indexOf(",") !== -1){
      val.split(",").join(", ");
    }
    row.append('<td>'+val+'&nbsp;</td>');
  });
  return row;
}
```

This all works and is quite lovely in Chrome/FF/Safari, but it causes IE to grash most ungracefully. IE pops up a window reporting a crash and reloads the page. No mention of what caused the problem in the console. Additionally, any and all debugging statements in this code runs and is displayed to the console before the crash, so I haven't been able to pinpoint where it's happening.

Anyone know what I'm missing?

Comment: Try a reboot? IE shouldn't just crash like that.

Comment: Seems to happen pretty consistently across the three machines I've tried it on, persisting across reboots. IE10 on Windows 7 in all instances, with both jquery 1.9.1 and 1.10.

Comment: You could do a binary search to find the cause.  Start comment out half the code until the crash doesn't happen, then uncomment incrementally until you find the line causing the crash.  The runtime state can then be examined.

Comment: Probably unrelated, but it looks like "row" and "val" are being set globally in build_row().